# Use imagePullSecrets in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, openshift, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Here's a snippet from my Jenkinsfile I use to create a dynamic pod

```
agent {
        kubernetes {
            label "hello-stage"
            cloud "some-cloud"
            defaultContainer "jnlp"
            idleMinutes 1
            containerTemplate {
                name 'jnlp'
                image 'some-image'
                alwaysPullImage true
                ttyEnabled true
                resourceRequestMemory '1Gi'
                resourceLimitMemory '2Gi' 
            }
            imagePullSecrets '["secret-name"]'
        } // kubernetes
    } // agent
```

Everything works except for the `imagePullSecrets`. I tried finding documentation with no luck. I'm new to using Jenkins with Kubernetes. Here's the error I get

```
WorkflowScript: 23: Invalid config option "imagePullSecrets" for agent type "kubernetes". Valid config options are [activeDeadlineSeconds, cloud, containerTemplate, containerTemplates, customWorkspace, defaultContainer, idleMinutes, inheritFrom, instanceCap, label, namespace, nodeSelector, podRetention, serviceAccount, slaveConnectTimeout, supplementalGroups, workingDir, yaml, yamlFile, yamlMergeStrategy] @ line 23, column 13.
            imagePullSecrets '["quay-operator-updates"]'
```

Could someone please help me figure out how to use imagePullSecrets with Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`containerTemplate` is now deprecated as mentioned [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/csanchez/jenkins/plugins/kubernetes/pipeline/KubernetesDeclarativeAgentScript.groovy)

Use the yaml syntax to pass the `imagePullSecrets` as follows :

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            yaml """\
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        metadata:
            name: 'jenkins-slave'
            namespace: 'your-namespace'
        spec:
            containers:
            - name: jnlp
              image: jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-9-alpine
              tty: true
            - name: demo-application
              image: some-image
              imagePullSecrets:
                  - name: your-secret
              tty: true

        """.stripIndent()
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('run app') {
            steps {
                container('demo-application') {
                    echo POD_CONTAINER
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I set the value of `your-secret`?